# Hibernate and java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I am trying to run the project with Hibernate and Maven. As a result I get the next message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError:     Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at square.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:20)
    at square.Main.main(Main.java:7)
```

Where the problem may be? Maybe there is something wrong with added libs?
Other files are below.

Main.java

```
package square;
import org.hibernate.Session;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Square square = new Square();
        square.setSize(100);
        session.save(square);
        square = (Square) session.get(Square.class, square.getId());
        square.setSize(120);
        session.save(square);
        session.delete(square);
        session.flush();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

HibernateUtil.java

```
package square;
import java.io.File;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

public class HibernateUtil {
 private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    static{
        try {            
            sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure(new File("/hibernate.cgf.xml")).buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (ExceptionInInitializerError ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed: " + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Square.java

```
   package square;

    public class Square {
         private int size;
         private int id;
         Square(){ 
         }
         Square(int size){
             size = size;
         } 
        public int getSize(){
             return size;
         }
        public void setSize(int size){
             size = size;
         }
        public int getId(){
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(int id){
            id = id;
        }
    }
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>Square</groupId>
    <artifactId>Square</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Square</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
            <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
            <version>57.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency><!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/cglib/cglib-nodep -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.ga</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/cglib/cglib -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ow2.asm/asm-util -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm-util</artifactId>
            <version>5.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
            jdbc:mysql://localhost/squarebase
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">****</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">****</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <!-- Mapping files -->
        <mapping resource="/Square.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Square.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="square.Square" table="square">
        <id name="id" column="id" unsaved-value="null">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
       <property name="size" type="int" column="size"/> 
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've changed and recompiled the class without recompiling everything that depends on it. Do a clean build. Then run. Hope it will solve your issue.

### For second try,

you can change `cglib` and `asm-util version`. That also helps some people.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm-util</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

### Resource Link:

http://howtodoinjava.com/random-exceptions/solved-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror-implementing-class/

Comment: Thanks, but it does not help.